# Android findViewById argument cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, view, textview

I'm following a tutorial about `ArrayAdapter` and I have this xml file named `list_item.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#CC0033"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#3399FF"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And an `Activity` with this code inside that generates errors on the lines marked with an "X"

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);         X
holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);       X
holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);      X
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

The code is copied from the tutorial but I noticed that it works with Ids stated in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: i see you have views in `list_item.xml`. i misunderstood. could you post some more relevant code?

Comment: Not the answer, but you should definitely read this: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help you (better display your stack trace) but have you tried casting your `convertView` field as `RelativeLayout` during inflation?

As in:

```
convertView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

... which also implies, is `convertView` of type `RelativeLayout`, as your layout xml indicates?

And finally, this one occurred to me a couple of times and would actually cause serious issues at compile-level, make sure the `R` class you import is `yourpackage.R`, not `android.R`, or both if you need both. Otherwise it might very well be that you're looking in the wrong layout.